# É possível usar Joomla sem jQuery?

Tags: joomla

O título acabou sendo direto e auto-explicativo... Eu consigo usar joomla sem usar jQuery ou qualquer outra biblioteca "pesada"? 
Estou com o intuito de tirar qualquer framework do desenvolvimento, que infelizmente (e obrigatoriamente) deve ser em joomla, e usar apenas javascript puro em pequenas aplicações. Localmente, já vejo um delay muito grande na renderização do conteúdo devido ao load de quase 100kb extra.

Creio que uma biblioteca jQuery "resumida" apenas para as funções necessárias para carregamento do conteúdo já seria interessante, mas desconheço a existência de algo assim, apenas jquery minificado, o que já estou usando para tentar minimizar o impacto no desempenho.

Comment: Se quer algo leve, não use Joomla ou outro software que faça mais ou menos já que quase todos são bem pesados.

Comment: No momento, como coloquei, é obrigatório que eu faça em Joomla, ordens superiores... rsrs Odeio esses CMSs, mas já que estou usando, estou procurando soluções para o desempenho, caso eu achar a resposta, compartilharei aqui.

Comment: Então aceite ele como ele é.

Comment: Consegui encontrar um plugin russo, que remove o jquery do front do site, e deixa somente no front do adm que é necessário... já é algo hehe